# How to define a new ForEach struct to implement the index function while keeping its original syntax in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to define a new struct called `ForEach` to implement the index function which has the similar syntax to the SwiftUI `ForEach`.

```
struct ForEach<Data: RandomAccessCollection,Content: View>: View where Data.Element: Identifiable, Data.Element: Hashable {
    let data: Data
    @ViewBuilder let content: (Data.Index, Data.Element) -> Content
    
    init(_ data: Data, content: @escaping (Data.Index, Data.Element) -> Content) {
        self.data = data
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        SwiftUI.ForEach(Array(zip(data.indices, data)), id: \.1) { index, element in
            content(index, element)
        }
    }
}
```

```
ForEach(array) { index, item in
    // each item here
}
```

But after I define my custom `ForEach`. The original syntax doesn't work.

```
ForEach(array) { item in   // Doesn't work after defining my custom ForEach
}
```

For code reusing reason, I must keep the original syntax. So simply replacing `index` with `_` to avoid error doesn't work. How can I fix this? Or any alternative to the same function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use this. It will confuse people because nothing is mentioning what the `id` is.

This is what you were looking for:

https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Indexed.md

```swift
ForEach(collection.indexed(), id: \.index) {
  $0.index
  $0.element
```